# how to disable variable expansion when using bash "eval"

Tags: bash, eval, variable-expansion

hi I have following propertie file (something.properties)

```
SERVER1_PROPERTY1=123    
SERVER1_PROPERTY2=${SERVER1_PROPERTY1}/123
```

and following bash script fetching one of the properties:

```
#!/bin/bash

. something.properties

SRV="SERVER1"

eval PROPERTY2=\$${SRV}_PROPERTY2

echo $PROPERTY2
```

the result is:

```
123/123
```

but I want it to be

```
${SERVER1_PROPERTY1}/123
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expansion is done when you source the file (`. something.properties`).

Write `SERVER1_PROPERTY2='${SERVER1_PROPERTY1}/123'` in your properties files to disable expansion.